# Why human knowledge about small scale physics is growing much faster than knowledge about big scale phenomena?

Tags: material-science, space, nanoscience

According to Kardashev scale there are subzero types civilizations according to their expertise in small scale physics (e.g. nanotechnology), which are classified according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale) as:

> - Type I-minus is capable of manipulating objects over the scale of themselves: building structures, mining, joining and breaking solids.
> - Type II-minus is capable of manipulating genes and altering the development of living things, transplanting or replacing parts of themselves, reading and engineering their genetic code.
> - Type III-minus is capable of manipulating molecules and molecular bonds, creating new materials.
> - Type IV-minus is capable of manipulating individual atoms, creating nanotechnologies on the atomic scale and creating complex forms of artificial life.
> - Type V-minus is capable of manipulating the atomic nucleus and engineering the nucleons that compose it.
> - Type VI-minus is capable of manipulating the most elementary particles of matter (quarks and leptons) to create organized complexity among populations of elementary particles; culminating in:
> - Type Omega-minus is capable of manipulating the basic structure of space and time.

According to current stage of nanotechnology and materials science, it seems human technology passed Type III-minus, which looks remarkable. But I'm wondering in comparison to big scale physics (e.g. interstellar travel), still human's technology and knowledge look pretty infant. In fact, I'm interested to know what is the bottleneck for human advancement in big scale physics and technology in comparison to small scale ones? Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Voting down because it is primarily an opinion-based question.

Comment: @user190081 Not really an opinion based...! Cause there must be a reason for this discrepancy about human technology and knowledge.

Comment: @user190081 Voting up cause not necessarily if you don't know the answer it must fall under "opinion-based" category...

Comment: Why do you believe there is a bottleneck? Who said the various civilization rating scales are comparable much less than unique? We only know of one planet, anything else is speculation at best.

Comment: @JonCuster This is not related to find some planets which may be habitable or whatever. I'm just saying: with current technology we are able to modify materials in a fairly small scale such as nanotechnology but still we are not able to create a spaceship even with sub-light velocities. So, why?

Comment: You have no objective basis to determine if nanoscience or megascience is better developed. Sure, we can't create an interstellar ship. We also can't easily manipulate quarks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect the ability to manipulate nanomaterials to imply the ability to create feasible spaceships, I'm also not sure this is a physics question - the impediments to "big scale physics" (you really mean: big scale engineering) may well be e.g. economical instead of physical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Money. In two ways.

In one way it's cheaper to do the experiments. Most of the study of small objects, with the obvious exception of high energy physics (among others I'm sure), can be carried out in devices that fit somewhere between a tabletop and a typical industrial space. In contrast, you will likely need something larger to develop a space drive. On top of that, the equipment is likely to be cheaper if only for material reasons; the crane you need to lift a quantum computer is likely much less expensive than the one you need for an interstellar engine.

The other money part is that nanotech is big money. An interstellar engine gets you to the stars, but is that really profitable? And I don't mean money terms alone... if you develop a new capsule that can deliver molecules into living cells, that's got a billion uses. An interstellar drive probably has more than one, but not a lot.

It's basically all risk/reward. And you don't have to go to high-scale levels to see it. Why is there so little research in new fission plants in contrast to making solar panels better? Because the later is both easier to research in every way, and those techniques have lots of other applications.

Comment: So by considering the "money" as an important driving force for research, it seems human technology will never (or maybe too long from today) reach that level to create a spaceship for interstellar travels. But, I'm wondering why the US and Russia spent too much money to accelerate exploring the space (e.g. landing on moon) but right now even NASA more focuses on nanotechnology.

Comment: In that case you're talking politics, and I won't even *try* to figure *that* out!